# Defining nested class conditionally based on enclosing class template parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

A matrix has an LU factorization only if it is square (`M==N`). Is there a simple way to disable `class lu` and method `luFactorization` iff `M!=N` below?

```
template<int M, int N>
class matrix {

    // lots and lots of operators and stuff
    // ...

    class lu {
        // ...
    }

    lu luFactorization() {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Comment: You could use [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) for the function?

Comment: Template partial specialisation for `matrix<N,N>`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm not sure how. Trying to understand the link you posted.

Comment: @davmac `matrix<M,N>` comes with a *lot* of baggage (operators etc.). Is it possible to partially specialize it without repeating code?

Comment: @Museful move the baggage to a shared base class, perhaps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define "simple". :)

Template partial specialisation does work:

```
template <int M, int N>
class matrix {
    // class lu, function luFactorization *not* defined
};

template <int N>
class matrix<N,N> {
    // class lu, function luFactorization defined
    class lu { };
    lu luFactorisation() { /* ... */ }
};
```

If there is a lot of baggage that both variants should have, you may be able to move some or all of that baggage to a common superclass. You might also consider making `lu` and `luFactorisation` non-member templates.

Comment: a detail but OP asked for those class to be defined if M == N, and your comment suggests the opposite

Comment: Does the compiler see two definitions of, say, `matrix<2,2>` and choose the latest one?

Comment: @Museful I believe it's more complex than that - it's not about which is defined first, but the fact that one is a (partly) specialised version of the other. The specialised version will always be preferred.